# Magento2 Amasty free gift item removing on checkout page

Tags: magento2, free-shipping, free-gift

**Reviewers please don't Cancel/Close this request for 1 day**.

Hi Can anyone facing Amasty free gift product removing on checkout page while applying coupon code?

Here are the steps I have followed

1. Created 100% discount rule from admin end for one SKU.
2. Browsed the product in the fronted & added item to cart
3. Added free gift item to cart
4. Go to checkout page added address & applied coupon code
5. Removed coupon code & again applied coupon code
6. Free gift item is removing from my cart

Could you please advise.

Note: If any one having this issue with Amasty Promo ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed by getting the below error on exception log in the magento 2.5.6 EE
Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26786  By Amit-Hariyaniz comment

> [2020-11-26 12:01:49] report.CRITICAL: Report ID:
> webapi-5fbf992dd28bd; Message: Infinite loop detected, review the
> trace for the looping path {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):
> Report ID: webapi-5fbf992dd28bd; Message: Infinite loop detected,
> review the trace for the looping path at
> /chroot/home/a58a79bd/north40.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208,
> LogicException(code: 0): Infinite loop detected, review the trace for
> the looping path at
> /chroot/home/a58a79bd/local.com/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php:241)"}
> []

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php**

Changed from

```
if($quote->getTotalsCollectedFlag() === false) {
  $quote->collectTotals(); 
}
```

**Changed To**

```
if($quote->getTotalsCollectedFlag() === false) {    
  //$quote->collectTotals(); 
 }
```